# yii model attribute cannot find

Tags: php, oop, yii

I am new to yii. In default actionLogin() method in SiteController, I am searching for where
`$model->attribtes` is defined?

`$model->attributes=$_POST['LoginForm'];`

I searched in LoginForm, CFormModel, CModel classes but I couldn't find. Is it a setter method?

Answer (score 4):

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/form.model#securing-attribute-assignments

After a model instance is created, we often need to populate its attributes with the data submitted by end-users. This can be done conveniently using the following massive assignment:

```
$model=new LoginForm;
if(isset($_POST['LoginForm']))
    $model->attributes=$_POST['LoginForm'];
```

The last statement is called massive assignment which assigns every entry in
$_POST['LoginForm'] to the corresponding model attribute. It is equivalent to the following assignments:

```
foreach($_POST['LoginForm'] as $name=>$value)
    {
        if($name is a safe attribute)
            $model->$name=$value;
    }
```

> Yii provides access to lots of other things via an instance
>   variable, such as database fields, relations, event handlers, and the
>   like. These "attributes" are a very powerful part of the Yii
>   framework, and though it's possible to use them without understanding,
>   one can't really use the full power without going under the covers a
>   bit.

`attributes` is a property of CActiveRecord, and yes, it has getter and setter method

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveRecord#attributes-detail

Then location where you would like to see

https://github.com/yiisoft/yii/blob/1.1.14/framework/db/ar/CActiveRecord.php#L754

Comment: Thanks for the answer Telvin. It is clear for me. But I still confused. In CAvctiveRecord class there is a property called $_attributes not $attributes. Then I printed the output of class_parents($model). It says this is inherited from CComponent. So I think $attributes propery is declared in __set() method in CComponent class.But I am not sure about this.

Comment: @Namal Check out the first few lines of the __get method of [CComponent](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CComponent#__get-detail). It let's you do $model->attributes and automatically tries to call $model->getAttributes().

Answer (score 1):

The 'attributes' property is really a getter/setter method(s) in the model. Passing an array to it will attempt to do a 'mass' setting of those attributes. All the elements in your $_POST['LoginForm'] need to have a corresponding attribute in the model. In the LoginForm model that comes with Yii, those are set as properties (i.e., `public $username;`), the `attributes` property will assign `$username` with the associated value in the array (`'username'=>'myusername'`).

Answer (score 0):

I printed the output of class_parents($model). It says this is inherited from CComponent. So I think $attributes propery is declared in __set() method in CComponent class.